# Physical meaning of transformation with symmetric matrices

Tags: transformation, symmetry, symmetric-matrices

$A$ is a symmetric matrix and $v$ is a vector.
I wonder if there is a physical/geometric meaning to the transformation $Av$ due to the symmetry in $A$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Spectral Theorem or (orthogonal) diagonalization?

Comment: Thanks, Kajelad. I know about the diagonalization. I'm just wondering if there's something else going on geometrically.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. That seems to be right. I couldn't find the post earlier.